Android Studio closes my project when minimizing the window or building/running the project
As the title suggests. I am forced to double click my project's "app" module and then close out of "Project Structure" menu in order to navigate through my project, each and every time I minimize Android Studio, and each time I attempt to build, clean, or run my project. This also happens with fresh, blank projects. I'm coming off of a 5 year hiatus from programming, just toying around with an app idea, so of course I had to run all the updates for Android Studio. Is there something I'm missing? A setting? Thanks for any help.


plz explain your problem a bit more as its not clear but this is what i got so ya
there u go enjoy :D
accept my Ans plz if i gave what u wanted

Thanks for giving it a shott :), but to be more specific, say I'm working on "example.java", and I minimize Android Studio for even a second, when I open the window back up, my file is closed and I have to re-open it. Doesn't matter how many files are open, they all close if I remove focus from Android Studio.

However, I will mark this as a solution because it led me to find my issue. See the "Autosave" section of the screenshot you posted. Checkbox for "Save files when switching to a different application or built-in terminal" and "Sync external changes: When switching to the IDE window or opening an editor tab". Unchecking both has solved my problem.

@zfollette nice :D
